# index names ignored with pd.read_excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, python-import

I am trying to import excel table but it doesn't correctly understand the names of the index columns. Plus, instead of None or np.nan it just substitutes the actual names as a second level index in the multiIndex. Any ideas how to fix both the names of the row multiIndex levels and the Nones (np.nans)?

[image]

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'tabular_and_graph_outputs\Book1.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1])

>>data.index
MultiIndex([(22, 'number'),
            (27, 'number')],
           names=['fnumber', 'number'])
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste your example data instead of posting an image? It would be a lot easier to answer your question that way.

Comment: But how can I paste it from excel? It automatically converts to image.